# The player that wants your to lose: the scorpion player?

Tags: terminology, game-theory

I believe I have heard the expression when someone did an analogy about nuclear war, comparing the danger to a game where the opposite player's objective is not to *win* but to make you lose. This was apparently called, in game theory, "a scorpion player".

I ***thought*** they were called the "scorpion player" but I can not find any proof or anything close to this.
Have I remembered wrong ? Is it an other name ? Or have hallucinated the whole thing ?

If anyone has any information on if there is a name for such player, I would be thankfull.

Many thanks.

Comment: you might want to try here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possibly related to the fable of the scorpion and the frog?

Answer (score 1):

as pointed out in the comments, you probably did NOT hallucinate this -- it's definitely based on [the fable of the scorpion and the frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scorpion_and_the_Frog).

Doesn't seem to be a popular term in game theory though -- I could only find a few references like https://www.spectacle.org/995/scorp.html

Maybe it was used in reference to a specific game, like a model of the fable?